# Placing Date before Title in Article Class in LaTeX

Tags: titles, article

I am writing an article in `TeX` and am using `article` class. I want the document date above its title, as in this case (the document is [here](https://www.minneapolisfed.org/research/sr/sr328.pdf)). How can I do this in `article` class? Is there a way I can do it with a `\maketitle` command?
[image]

Comment: If you want to submit your article somewhere, check what format they want you to send in and if it even matters where the date is in *your* output.

Comment: @Johannes_B I get that. But that clearly was not what I was after. I am writing a draft of my paper and I just want it to appear in a certain style, purely according to my own tastes. Of course, when it goes to a journal, it's a diferent ballgame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to modify the behavior of some standard command, you have two options:  look for a package that does it, or redefine the command itself.  I'll follow the second option here.

The `\maketitle` command is defined in `article.cls`, so it might be worth looking at that there.  However, if you're going to be doing this more than once, it's probably worth designing your own class, or at least a command for a `.sty` file that you can use repeatedly.

The long story is that `\maketitle` uses another command, `\@maketitle`, internally, so you'll have to redefine that.  I'll leave it as an exercise for you to look into the current definition (remember that there are two different forms:  one when the `titlepage` option is used and one when it isn't), but I'd suggest you do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{flushleft}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
     {\normalsize Federal Reserve Bank of Minneapolis \par}
     {\normalsize Research Department Staff Report 328 \par}
     \vskip\baselineskip%
     {\normalsize Revised \@date \par}
     \vskip3\baselineskip%
     {\LARGE \textbf{\@title} \par}%
    \vskip\baselineskip%
     { \@author \par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\normalsize University of Minnesota \\ and Federal Reserve
      Bank of Minneapolis}%
  \end{flushleft}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
\title{Business Cycle Accounting}
\author{V.~V.~Chari}
\date{December 2006}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It might be that you'd like to define helper commands like `\organization` or `\fedbranch` to help automate this more.  But the above will give you this:

[image: Results]

Which seems a reasonable facsimile of what you need.  Tweaking and automating this should be pretty straightforward.

Hope that helps!