# Author before title in the title page of article class

Tags: article, author, titling

`\maketitle` in the article class prints the title above the author but I want to reverse that and print the author above the title. Any suggestions?

```
\title{Can you find the solution?}
\author{you}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

There's, of course, this solution but it is far from pretty

```
\begingroup
    \centering
    \large You

    \LARGE Can you find the solution?
\endgroup
```

There's also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519481/placing-date-before-title-in-article-class-in-latex?rq=1) solution whereby I guess I would simply replace date with author but there seems to be a lot of additional styling embedded in there that are not necessary in my case.

Comment: With the  `titlepage` environment?

Comment: @Bernard not necessarily but if it would be easier then yes. Currently, I'm declaring the titlepage argument in the documentclass options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per its definition in the `article` document class, if the `titlepage` option is *not* set, the `\maketitle` macro eventually calls the `\@maketitle` macro which, in turn, is defined as follows:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

Note, in particular, the instructions `\@title`, `\@author`, and `\@date` instructions, and observe that they're contained in TeX groups for which `\LARGE`, `\large`, and `\large` are in effect.

To force LaTeX to typeset the author-related information before the `title`-related information, you could redefine `\@maketitle` as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 2.5em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
```

Note the four `\vskip` directives. Naturally, you're free to change their arguments to suit your tastes.

A full MWE -- screenshot not necessary, I believe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 2.5em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

---

---

If, on the other hand, the `titlepage` option *is* set, the `\maketitle` macro does not invoke a subsidiary macro called `\@maketitle`. In that case, it's necessary to redefine the `\maketitle` macro directly, say as follows:

```
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large \@date \par}%      
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: thanks! This works as requested. However, I'm using `fullpage` package for slimmer margins but with the re-defined command, the margins return to the article class default

Comment: @GeneBurinsky - Pleas see the addendum I just posted, on how to redefine `\maketitle` if the `titlepage` option is set. Does the addendum also work with `fullpage`? (It would have been useful if you'd mentioned that you use this package -- which I'm not familiar with, incidentally -- up front.)

Comment: thank you! The `titlepage` overwrite preserves the margins set by the `fullpage` package and everything works like a charm.